# How to modify custom.xml within docx using python

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree, python-docx

I've been using python-docx to programmatically change parts of a word document (*.docx) that needs to be updated monthly. My problem now lies with editing custom properties in the template, specifically the 'Date Completed' property.

[Custom template properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAzdA.png)

My current simplified python code is as follows:

```
import python-docx
doc = docx.Document('MonthlyUpdate.docx')
help(doc.core_properties)  #only shows author, category, etc, but no 'Date Completed'
```

The relevant file appears to be in *.docx\docProps\**custom.xml**, but I'm unsure of how to edit that file within python 2.7. Is it possible through python-docx or would I need to dive into lxml/etree modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality hasn't been implemented yet. There's a feature request open for it and one user has done some work on it you can find linked to from there.

https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/91

I think this would require using his fork, so you might not get all the latest features, depending on the version the fork is based on.

Comment: Cool, so I could do "pip install https://github.com/renejsum/python-docx/archive/master.zip" as a temporary workaround until the pull request gets implemented, and follow the example [here](https://gist.github.com/renejsum/0ea621aabd0e4640391ddb3e361f6c02).

Comment: @weiji14: don't forget to accept an answer. That's how respondents are "paid" for their work here on SO :)

Comment: Thanks for your help pointing me in the right direction. I've managed to change those custom_properties but I still have to manually press Ctrl-A and then F9 to update the field in my document. Better than nothing though.

Comment: @weiji14: If you have flexibility about which property you use, you might consider the `modified` property in core properties: http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#coreproperties-objects

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the OP, I only wish to read some targeted bits from Word documents, not write them. "python-docx" looks like a good fit, but some of the info I need to extract resides in Custom Properties.
I see that progress is being made on the feature proper with read and write:
https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/91

In the interim, I intend to use this simple peek, to work around that gap:

```
import zipfile
import lxml
import lxml.etree
handlea = zipfile.ZipFile("MY.docx")
handleb = handlea.open("docProps/custom.xml")
xml = lxml.etree.parse(handleb)
handleb.close()
handlea.close()
root = xml.getroot()
name_to_value = {}
for element in root:
    name_to_value[element.attrib["name"]] = element[0].text
print (name_to_value)
```

If anyone has a better workaround, for the simpler task of *reading* custom properties via "python-docx", I'd welcome the nudge!